# Gazebo on Wsl font size menu problem/scaling?

Tags: gazebo

Hey I am new to gazebo and i have been trying to solve the problem in many ways and spend quite a while doing research but I couldnt find how to resolve it.
Basically the menu size is very small as you can see on the image.
Thank you!

[image]